# '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5]
list2=[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005]
list3=[0.05, -0.07, -0.08, 0.004, -0.02, -0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.06]
```

So these are my 3 lists that are used

```
for l2,l1 in zip(list2,list1):
    if list3>= 0.04: #where the type error issue has occurred
        print(f"{l2} and {l1}")
```

Any ways to fix this coding or improve it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately it's hord to understand what do you want to achieve. You zip two lists and iterate over the pairs, but list3 is not an element but an entire third list which you try to compare to 0.04 on every iteration.

Comment: @Shmygol tbh this is a project im working on and im quite confuse as of what im doing as well but the output im suppose to get is for example since list3[0] >=0.04, the output will be "1 and 2001" and if others is more than or equal to 0.04 it will be printed as well

Comment: What does represent the values in `list1`? BTW it's a good example why you should use proper names. `list2` looks like a list of years, so call it `years`, `list3` is probably `temperatures`. And what is `list1`? I have fealing, that sizes should match.

Comment: @Shmygol no worries I got the answers to my question already thanks for tryin to help , appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for l1,l2,l3 in zip(list1,list2,list3):
    if l3>= 0.04: 
        print(f"{l2} and {l1}")
```

Notice that lengths of list1 and list2 are smaller than the length of list3. Therefore this for loop won't iterate through the end of the list3. 
Output will be:

```py
2001 and 1
```

Comment: Thanks I learnt a lot through this

Comment: @Student.py please pay attention, that the half of the elements of `list3` is just ignored in this snipped.

Comment: Yeah i tbh list 1 and list 2 i had to make it easier to type so values are actually different from the real list I want to see some examples on how to approach this questions. I dont want to copy and paste what I have so i can type and change the stuff myself to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to do but I think you want to print the `list1` and `list2` elements if the `list3` element is greater than `0.04`.

If you want to do the above thing, you can use the [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) for it. The enumerate add the list index to the `for` loop.

**Code:**

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005]
list3 = [0.05, -0.07, -0.08, 0.004, -0.02, -0.03, 0.03, 0.02, 0.06]

for idx, l3 in enumerate(list3):
    if idx > len(list1) or idx > len(list2):
        break
    if l3 >= 0.04:
        print(f"{list1[idx]} and {list2[idx]}")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
1 and 2001
```

Comment: Thank you sir it worked learnt a lot from this